# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - how to get URL though CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am fairly new to AWS, I wrote a script to create a ElasticBeanstalk server and deploy code to it which works fine

I am able to get the IP Address and Instance ID using

```
aws ec2 describe-instances
```

I know a typical HTTP URL looks like this

```
http://(cname-prefix).(region).elasticbeanstalk.com
```

and I used it to "generate" the URL in the script

But I want to check if we can get the URL using CLI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The AWS CLI has a command for this, it describes the elastic beanstalk environment and one of the resulting values is the Endpoint URL

For load-balanced, autoscaling environments, it returns the URL to the LoadBalancer. For single-instance environments, the IP address of the instance is returned.

See [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/describe-environments.html)

`aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments --environment-names my-env`

The output looks like this:

```
{
"Environments": [
    {
        "ApplicationName": "my-app",
        "EnvironmentName": "my-env",
        "VersionLabel": "7f58-stage-150812_025409",
        "Status": "Ready",
        "EnvironmentId": "e-rpqsewtp2j",
        "EndpointURL": "awseb-e-w-AWSEBLoa-1483140XB0Q4L-109QXY8121.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com",
        "SolutionStackName": "64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v2.0.0 running Tomcat 8 Java 8",
        "CNAME": "my-env.elasticbeanstalk.com",
        "Health": "Green",
        "AbortableOperationInProgress": false,
        "Tier": {
            "Version": " ",
            "Type": "Standard",
            "Name": "WebServer"
        },
        "DateUpdated": "2015-08-12T18:16:55.019Z",
        "DateCreated": "2015-08-07T20:48:49.599Z"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tom,I used 
`aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments --environment-names my-app --query "Environments[*].CNAME" --output text`